# Need help understanding the output of the program

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I was working with ma project XYZ

and I got stuck in extracting text in from the source

```
<a href="/gifts" class="title" data-tracking-id="mdd-heading">gifts</a>
```

I want to extrack the href as content

I tried this

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from XYZ.items import XYZ
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "main"
    allowed_domains = ["XYZ"]
    start_urls = ["XYZ"]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//a[@data-tracking-id='mdd-heading']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = XYZ()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
            print "www.xyz.com"+str(item["link"])
        return items
```

and the `output` was

```
www.xyz.com[u'/gifts']
```

I was expecting output as

```
www.xyz.com/gifts
```

What i did wrong.... ?

Comment: `item['link']` is clearly a list; use its first element instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`Selector`'s `extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract):

> extract()
>
> Serialize and return the matched nodes as a list of unicode
>   strings. Percent encoded content is unquoted.

So, `extract()` returns a list and you need the first item from it. Use `item['link'][0]`.

Also, there are other problems in the code:

- `for titles in titles` loop doesn't make sense, you need a separate loop variable
- `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated, use `Selector`
- use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join the parts of a url

Here's the complete code with fixes and other improvements:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from XYZ.items import XYZ


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "main"
    allowed_domains = ["XYZ"]
    start_urls = ["XYZ"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//a[@data-tracking-id='mdd-heading']")
        for title in titles:
            item = XYZ()
            item ["title"] = title.xpath("text()").extract()[0]
            item ["link"] = title.xpath("@href").extract()[0]
            print urljoin("www.xyz.com", item["link"])

            yield item
```